# Calculating XIRR using R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to calculate IRR (internal rate of return) for non-periodic cashflows using R (similar to the Excel function named XIRR). The only problem is that it doesn't work. I sure could use some help in figuring out what's is going wrong..

```
R>cashflow <- c(275,275,275,275,275,275,275,275,275,275,275,275,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,416.833333333333,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,452.666666666667,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,534.583333333333,-9246.969046)
R>dates <- c("1997-01-31","1997-02-28","1997-03-31","1997-04-30","1997-05-31","1997-06-30","1997-07-31","1997-08-31","1997-09-30","1997-10-31","1997-11-30","1997-12-31","1998-01-31","1998-02-28","1998-03-31","1998-04-30","1998-05-31","1998-06-30","1998-07-31","1998-08-31","1998-09-30","1998-10-31","1998-11-30","1998-12-31","1999-01-31","1999-02-28","1999-03-31","1999-04-30","1999-05-31","1999-06-30","1999-07-31","1999-08-31","1999-09-30","1999-10-31","1999-11-30","1999-12-31","2000-01-31","2000-02-29","2000-03-31","2000-04-30","2000-05-31","2000-06-30","2000-07-31","2000-08-31","2000-09-30","2000-10-31","2000-11-30","2000-12-31","2001-01-31")

R>irr <- xirr(cashflow, dates)
```

it throws the error :

`Error in while (pchg >= tol & abs(fval) > tol & iter <= itmax) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Here's the function:

```
xirr <- function(cf, dates) {

 # Secant method.
secant <- function(par, fn, tol=1.e-07, itmax = 100, trace=FALSE, ...) { 
    # par = a starting vector with 2 starting values 
    # fn = a function whose first argument is the variable of interest 
    if (length(par) != 2) stop("You must specify a starting parameter vector of length 2") 
    p.2 <- par[1] 
    p.1 <- par[2] 
    f <- rep(NA, length(par)) 
    f[1] <- fn(p.1, ...) 
    f[2] <- fn(p.2, ...) 
    iter <- 1 
    pchg <- abs(p.2 - p.1) 
    fval <- f[2] 
    if (trace) cat("par: ", par, "fval: ", f, "\n") 
    while (pchg >= tol & abs(fval) > tol & iter <= itmax) { 
        p.new <- p.2 - (p.2 - p.1) * f[2] / (f[2] - f[1]) 
        pchg <- abs(p.new - p.2) 
        fval <- fn(p.new, ...) 
        p.1 <- p.2 
        p.2 <- p.new 
        f[1] <- f[2] 
        f[2] <- fval 
        iter <- iter + 1 
        if (trace) cat("par: ", p.new, "fval: ", fval, "\n") 
    } 
    list(par = p.new, value = fval, iter=iter) 
} 

# Net present value.
npv <- function(irr, cashflow, times) sum(cashflow / (1 + irr)^times) 

times <- as.numeric(difftime(dates, dates[1], units="days"))/365.24 

r <- secant(par=c(0,0.1), fn=npv, cashflow=cf, times=times) 

return(r$par)
}
```

Comment: In cases such as this, try stepping through your functions (this is a fundamental technique in debugging). After 56 iterations, `p.2==-Inf` so that `fval==NaN`, and R cannot assign a truth value to your condition `abs(fval) > tol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mathematical problem, not a programming problem;

Towards a rate of return of −100% the net present value approaches infinity with the sign of the last cash flow, therefore the internal rate of return can't be calculated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me thank you for making this post, since I've been looking for such a function for quite a while. 
Still your function doesn't control for `NaN`. You should change the expression for `[fval]` in the `while` loop to

```
fval <- ifelse(is.na(fn(p.new, ...)),1,fn(p.new, ...))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `xirr` function in the `tvm` package.

```
library(tvm)

xirr_value <- xirr(cashflow, dates)
```

Hope this helps.