# Evaluate Excel File Without Opening/Saving

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is there a way to calculate excel formulas without opening the file manually? If openxlsx is not the best option please feel free to suggest other packages. Thanks!

My goal is to paste data into an excel file (already existing) with formulas referencing the range that i am pasting data to and have excel refresh it's formulas and calculate summary stats(sums for example). I would like to update the formulas with R code and save the file so that i can read the summary values into R without opening/saving the excel file.

**I want to remove the manual step (Bold below).**

Workbook that i am using has two sheets: rawData and summary. the only data before i start in the file is the sum formulas on A2:D2. 
A2 contains =SUM(rawData!A:A)

```
require("openxlsx")
wb <- loadWorkbook("MyTestWorkBook.xlsx")
writeData(wb,iris, sheet="rawData")
saveWorkbook(wb,"MyTestWorkBook.xlsx",overwrite = TRUE)
```

From here I have the sheet 'summary' with sums of each column.
I read the sheet.

```
read.xlsx("MyTestWorkBook.xlsx","summary")
  sumA sumB sumC sumD
1    0    0    0    0
```

**I now manually open workbook (not with R) and save**

```
read.xlsx("MyTestWorkBook.xlsx","summary")
   sumA  sumB  sumC  sumD
1 876.5 458.6 563.7 179.9
```

Formulas have now calculated.

Comment: I don't think you can get excel to update the formulas from outside of excel.  instead why not create the summary page in R and then output to excel?

Comment: Agreed, I'm pretty sure Excel won't calculate anything until you open it. So even if you use R to write the Excel formulas, those values won't populate until you open the workbook in Excel.

Comment: Okay thanks! I cannot create summary in R b/c the calculation (XIRR) will sometimes fail to calculate in R and i need to confirm that it will also not calcuate in excel. thanks

Comment: You might reference this question in regards to XIRR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259575/calculating-xirr-using-r

Comment: Thanks we have a good XIRR function that works 99% of the time. it really only has issues with very negative IRRs, which excel seems to calculate better.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to deal with this, but it is not the most elegant. The solution is executing the following function right after you use saveWorkbook() and before you read data from the workbook you just saved:

```
calculate_wb_fn <- function(excel_file_directory, excel_file_name)
{
  macro_calculate_wb <- file(paste0(excel_file_directory,"macro_calculate_wb.vbs") )
  writeLines(c("Const xlVisible = -1",
               "Dim objExcel",
               "Dim objWb",
               "Dim objws",
               "Dim strFileName",
               paste0("strFileName = \"",gsub("/","\\\\",excel_file_directory),excel_file_name,"\""),
               "On Error Resume Next",
               "Set objExcel = CreateObject(\"excel.application\")",
               "Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)",
               "objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False",
               "objWb.Save",
               "objWb.Close SaveChanges=True",
               "objExcel.Close",
               "objExcel.Quit",
               "set objWb = Nothing",
               "set objExcel = Nothing",
               "On Error GoTo 0")
             , macro_calculate_wb)

  close(macro_calculate_wb)


  file <- normalizePath(paste0(excel_file_directory,"macro_calculate_wb.vbs") )


  shell(shQuote(string = file), wait = T)

  file.remove(paste0(excel_file_directory,"macro_calculate_wb.vbs"))
}
```

The function creates a file with a VBscript that opens the file, saves it (i.e., also calculates it), and closes it. Then it executes the script, and then it deletes the script.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I found the RDCOMClient package a simple way to do this.

```
outputfile <- "filenameblahblah.xlsx"

library(RDCOMClient)

# Create COM Connection to Excel
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE
xlApp[['DisplayAlerts']] <- FALSE

# Open workbook
xlWB <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Open(outputfile)
xlWB$Save()
xlWB$Close(TRUE)
```

Note that RCDOMClient apparently only works on Windows machines and you may have have to install it using `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")`

Answer (score 1):

The following function works on my end :

```
force_Calculation_Excel_Formula <- function(file_name)
{
    library(excel.link)
    app <- xl.workbook.open(filename = file_name)
    app[["Statusbar"]] <- ""
    app[["Screenupdating"]] <- TRUE
    app[["Calculation"]] <- xl.constants$xlCalculationManual
    invisible(NULL)
    xl.workbook.save(filename_Save)
    xl.workbook.close()
    system("taskkill /IM Excel.exe")
}
```