# Make R-script update equations in Excel

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I need help with a hybrid R-Excel problem. I use an R-script with the "openxlsx" package, to open an Excel XLSX file. I then take some content that has been created by the R-script - a vector of numbers - and copy that into the Excel file. The Excel file is then saved with a new filename. If I **manually** open the new Excel file I can see that the data has been correctly copied, and I can see that other derived values have been computed. However, if I re-open the saved Excel file from within the R-script, the derived values have not yet been evaluated. My problem is that I must be able to obtain the derived values for the R-script to do its thing. I cannot figure out how to trigger the evaluation of the Excel formulas without manually opening the file "by hand." A snippet of the R-code follows:

[image: Excel-R problem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate Excel File Without Opening/Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952207/evaluate-excel-file-without-opening-saving)